# MasterCard Payment Integration in Website Using PHP

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, mastercard

I have one website on which i implement Paypal payment integration successfully now i want to implement Mastercard payment integration but i did not know from where i should start and which API i used etc..

I go through their [website](https://developer.mastercard.com/page/php-sdk-guide#debugging) but i did not understand properly like from where should i start and what are the requirement to accept the payments

Comment: Clarify your programming language, please?

Comment: Have you tried following the steps on https://developer.mastercard.com/page/php-sdk-guide#getting-started ? At what point do you reach problems?

Comment: Paypal actually supports payments with Mastercard and Visa for people without Paypal accounts.  Online card payments are generally done through payment gateways - WorldPay is a well known one.  They all have their own APIs

Answer (score -1):

You or your client must setup a merchant account to accept credit cards first and then implement the MID through a payment integration with a payment gateway API or a direct processor in order to have the business owner of a website accept Visa MasterCard Discover and American Express.